# How to improve the performance for a UITableViewCell with too many UITextViews?

Tags: ios, uitextview, uitableview

I have an UITableViewCell with too many UITextViews, and I've been having bad performance.

I want to draw the text, and when the user taps the text to try to edit, put a real UITextView there.

How could I implement that?

Comment: first of all, it is `UITableView`. How can you put a lot `UITextView` inside your UITableView? I don't understand. Clarify needed.

Comment: OK, then the question is: draw the contents directly in the table view cell's content view, when the user tap the content to try to edit it, put a uitextview there, after the cell lost focus, the cell's uitextview will be released and redraw the inputed contents.

Answer (score 0):

In the [iOS Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/) you have an example named [TableViewSuite](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318), here you have some examples of how to implement `UITableView's`, the last example (number 5) features the best way of implement an UITableView featuring performance so I suggest you to check this example.

Description of the `TableViewSuite` project:

> This sample shows how to use UITableView through a progression of
>   increasingly advanced applications that display information about time
>   zones.
>
> When implementing a table view cell, there's a tension between optimal
>   scrolling performance and optimal edit/reordering performance. You
>   should typically use subviews in the cell's content view.
>
> When you have an edit or reordering control, using subviews makes the
>   implementation easier, and the animations perform better because UIKit
>   doesn't have to redraw during animations.
>
> Subviews have two costs:
>
> 1) Initialization. This can be largely mitigated by reusing table
>   cells. 2) Compositing. This can be largely mitigated by making the
>   views opaque. Often, one translucent subview is fine, but more than
>   one frequently causes frame drops while scrolling.
>
> If the content is complex, however (more than about three subviews),
>   scrolling performance may suffer. If this becomes a problem, you can
>   instead draw directly in a subview of the table view cell's content
>   view.
>
> The fifth example is an extension of the fourth. It displays even more
>   information about each time zone, such as the time and relative day in
>   that time zone. Its shows how you can create a custom table view cell
>   that contains a custom view that draws its content in -drawRect:.

Comment: Yes, I have try to draw directly in a subview of the table view cell's content view. But if I need edit the cell, so I should insert a real uitextview, after the user finishes editing, then redrawing the content. How to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `UITextView` as subview under the `UITableViewCell`.

In `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` , you can add the UITextView as follow:

```
// Assume cell is a UITextView *
UITextView *txtView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 30, 100, 30)];
[cell addSubview:txtView];

return cell;
```

Comment: using subviews makes the implementation easier, but scrolling performance may suffer.   So I draw directly in a subview of the table view cell's content view, and insert a uitextview when the user try to edit it.